# specflow test getting skipped

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

I am trying to write bdd test using specflow  Test gets skipped with exception

> Execution framework error: TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.SpecRunException: At least one test thread aborted.

Below is my code I have attached test result page

```
   [Binding]
    public class LoginToGmailSteps
    {

        public IWebDriver Idriver;

       [BeforeTestRun]
        public static void BeforeTestRun(IWebDriver Idriver)
        {
            Idriver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Users\\gayat\\Desktop\\Test projects\\LoginToGmail");
        }

        [AfterTestRun]
        public static void AfterTestRun(IWebDriver Idriver)
        {
            Idriver.Dispose();
        }

        [Given(@"I am on Gmail login page")]
        public void GivenIAmOnGmailLoginPage()
        {

            Idriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/gmail/");
            Idriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            IWebElement signin = Idriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sign in"));
            signin.Click();
        }

        [Given(@"I have entered email address")]
        public void GivenIHaveEnteredEmailAddress()
        {

            IWebElement EmailInput = Idriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type]='email'"));
            EmailInput.SendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
        }

        [Given(@"I have entered password")]
        public void GivenIHaveEnteredPassword()
        {

            IWebElement PwdInput = Idriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type]='password'"));
            PwdInput.SendKeys("abcd[specflow ][1]");
        }

        [When(@"I press login button")]
        public void WhenIPressLoginButton()
        {
            IWebElement NextButton = Idriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[id]='passwordNext'"));
            NextButton.Click();

        }

        //[Then(@"inbox is displayed")]
        //public void ThenInboxIsDisplayed()
        //{
        //    Idriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.upwork.com/ab/find-work/");
        //}
    }
```

[image: exception details]

Comment: The `IWebdirver Idriver` argument to your `BeforeTestRun` is not being used. Try removing that. The stack trace you posted mentions that it cannot resolve interface IWebDriver.

Comment: Also, please do not post images of the stack trace. Copy and paste the text into your question, so it is easier to read, and copy-and-paste into an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply That  was a funny mistake from my side :-)

Comment: But now i have a issue that multiple browser windows are getting opened now

Comment: Are you initializing a new ChromeDriver in multiple step definition classes? You get one browser window per ChromeDriver instance.